# How to speed up node service

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have two collections `categorytypes` and `categories`, each category type has multiple categories. When I am fetching all category details in each index of category there should be a a filed of category_type giving all details of category_type.

My code is:

```
exports.findAllWithParentChild = (req, res) => {
    let resData = [];
    Models.Category.find()
    .then(data => {
        var results = [];
        async.each(data,function(cat,callback) { 
            console.log(cat.categorytype_id)
            Models.CategoryType.findOne({'_id' : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(cat.categorytype_id)},function(err,catType) {
            var obj = cat.toObject();
            obj.category_type = catType;
            results.push(obj);
            callback(err);
        });            
    },
    function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send({
            response: true,
            message: "Category deleted successfully.",
            data : results
        });
     });
  });
};
```

And the format I need in response:

```
{
        "_id": "5cb78c44ede6452278d13fbe",
        "title": "fhhghgf",
        "description": "hgfhgf",
        "slug": "hgfhgfhgf",
        "categorytype_id": "5cb78ba8ede6452278d13fb6",
        "user_id": "hgfhgfh",
        "status": true,
        "created_at": "2019-04-17T20:27:48.821Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-17T20:27:48.821Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "category_type": {
            "_id": "5cb78ba8ede6452278d13fb6",
            "title": "asde",
            "description": "asde",
            "slug": "asde",
            "user_id": "asde",
            "status": true,
            "created_at": "2019-04-17T20:25:12.863Z",
            "updated_at": "2019-04-17T20:25:12.863Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    },
```

Is there any better way? Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Have you looked into [Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)?

Comment: I am using node for the first time. Could you please refer any proper tutorial for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change your code with below one and check the output**

```
exports.findAllWithParentChild = (req, res) => {
    Models.Category.find({}).
    populate('categorytypes'). 
    exec(function (err, data) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log('Success', data);
    });
};
```

Comment: Giving only categories data in response

Comment: @AmalenduKar also add your both models here so that i can check the relation between category and categorytypes.